# Regex to replace only links without replacing the src attributes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace the urls in the block of text with clickable link while rendering.

The regex am using :

```
/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig
```

Example

```
This is the text i got from http://www.sample.com
```

it should be converted to

```
This is the text i got from
 <a href="http://www.sample.com">http://www.sample.com</a>
```

the problem is when the text having the img tag , then the src attribute also getting replaced which i don't want.

Kindly help me to replace only direct links not the links in the src="" attributes

Thanks

Comment: Check [how to wrap urls with anchor tag and ignore urls that already have anchor tags in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22541041/3832970)

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative look-behind assertion at the beginning of your regex, to search only for strings not after `src="`:

```
(?<!src=")
```

Edit: Unfortunately look-behind assertions do not work in javascript regexes. Alternatively, you can use a negative look-ahead assertion like this:

```
((?!src=").{0,4})
```

remembering that you need to use the matched string in the replacement (otherwise you would delete 4 characters before `http://`).